# In an SVM built in sklearn, what is the predicted output that would be included in the squared hinge loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

If my SVM for a `-1` sample, has a decision function value of `-1.32`, for example, and then an actual prediction of `-1`.

Which value would I pass to my loss function as `y_pred`? Would it be the decision function value or the actual prediction as I would assume?

I just need a bit of a check just in case.

Comment: y_pred generally means what your model predicted, so -1.

Comment: Hi. This seems to be only a programming issue. Am I right? If yes, I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow. If not, please, explain why by editing your post and clarifying it. Programming issues are generally off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more info.

Comment: I suppose so, feel free to migrate.

Comment: @FeedMeInformation Ok, I will migrate it. Please, next time, use `@nbro` so that I receive a notification of your comment. It was just luck that I saw your last comment above :P